# Will Unity 2D make performance quicker than regular Unity?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, gpu

I'm just looking for a way to speed up overall quickness around the OS. I'm on a fairly new HP box so it shouldn't lag as much as it does.

Also, is there anything LIGHTER than Unity 2D that I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Following these instructions:

- [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

will install only a few kb of packages and give you a lightweight and gnome2 like experience.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of the best places to start would be trying to find out what is causing excess lag to begin with. I would try opening terminal and using `top` to find out which process(es?) are causing the lag.

---

Also, you might want to try Xubuntu which is based on XFCE and is intended to be lighter than others.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

http://xubuntu.org/

To remove everything but the Xubuntu desktop folow steps on this link -
http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu

---

Also, Lubuntu is another lightweight desktop which is based on LXDE.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

http://lubuntu.net/

To remove everything but the Lubuntu desktop folow steps on this link -
http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelubuntu